# Serre fibrations between spaces of embeddings-Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, geometric-topology

Given topological manifolds $M,N$ of the same dimension, let $\operatorname{Emb}(M,N)$ denote the subspace of $\operatorname{Map}(M,N)$ consisting of the (topological) embeddings $M\to N$. Here $\operatorname{Map}(M,N)$ is equipped with the compact-open topology.

It is stated in Notation 5.4.1.9 of Jacob Lurie's *Higher Algebra* that, if $M$ is a topological manifold of dimension $k$, the map  $$\operatorname{Emb}(\mathbb{R}^k,M)\to M$$ induced by the evaluation at $0\in\mathbb{R}^k$ is a Serre fibration.

This probably has to do with some variation of the isotopy extension theorem. Unfortunately I am not conversant with manifold topology. Does anyone know a refernce  (or a proof, if it is short enough to fit into this page) for this claim? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very, very overkill but the reference in the second answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145636/isotopy-extension-theorems) implies it if $M$ is dimension at least 3. I think it should also be fairly easy to describe some local trivializations.

Comment: Cross-posted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447782/reference-request-fibrations-between-spaces-of-embeddings